# mongodb replica set with multiple primaries and pingMS=0

Tags: mongodb, replication

I am trying to set a replica set with two nodes: Node0 and Node1. From the Node0 I initialized a replica set named "rs0" and added Node1 to it. The problem is that it is added as a primary node instead of a secondary node and the final result is a replica set with two primary nodes.

This is the result of executing the `rs.status()` command from Node0

```
   "set" : "rs0",
        "date" : ISODate("2012-10-23T21:03:37Z"),
        "myState" : 1,
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "Node0:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 61185,
                        "optime" : Timestamp(1350967947000, 1),
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2012-10-23T04:52:27Z"),
                        "self" : true
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "name" : "Node1:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 58270,
                        "optime" : Timestamp(1350956423000, 1),
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2012-10-23T01:40:23Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2012-10-23T21:03:37Z"),
                        "pingMs" : 0
                }
        ],
```

If I execute the same command from Node1 the only node listed is itself. Note that the pingMs is 0. Trying to add a third node or an arbiter give similar results: each one is added as primary and the pingMS is always 0.

Comment: Hi, can you describe how you started the mongod processes on the nodes (which parameters)? Did you use the --replSet option? Are they running on different servers? How did you add the other node to the set?

Comment: ping being 0 is absolutely normal (for example) for two mongod processes that are running on the same host (no network latency at all) - since that's frequently done in testing or training ping 0 in itself is absolutely not an indication that something is wrong.  Two PRIMARY nodes _is_ an indication of something wrong however :)  - could you provide at least parts of the logs for these two servers?

Comment: @Thomas I ran a mongod process with a configuration file: the only parameters that I specified were replSet=rs0 and fork=true. I am running it on different servers in the 27017 port. I added the node executing rs.add("node1") from the node0 (after executing rs.initiate() in both servers).

Comment: Same problem here. This issue have been reported to mongoDb since January 2013 [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8145). JFYI

Answer (score 5):

You mentioned that you run `rs.initiate()` on both servers. This should only be done on one.

I suggest you start from scratch, by deleting the dbpath directory for each node (backup data before if the db was not empty). Then, start all mongod processes, log into one of them, then call

- `rs.initiate()`
- `rs.add(<other node 1>)`

The other node gets the replica set configuration through the first one automatically. Repeat `rs.add() for each additional node you want to add.

Comment: Okay, but is there no cleaner way to do this? For example reconfigure the rs  on the secondary or removing the configuration, so that we do not have to "start from scratch"?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same situation, having wrongly run `rs.initiate()` on two instances. I solved this by shutting down the should-be second instance, removing the data directory and relaunching the instance. Upon restart, it is properly detected as a member of the replica set, is properly synchronized, and most importantly there is only one primary.

This operation should not be dangerous since, to my knowledge, a replica set replicate all the data on the nodes. To be sure, you could just move the data directory after the shutdown of secondary node, so that you would keep a backup in case anything went wrong.